# azure function app scaling with storage queue binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions

we are in the process of designing a solution where in we have

1. Azure Storage Queue
2. Azure function with Storage Queue input binding.

Questions

1. what would happen when we scale the function app, say if we have 2 instances of the function, will both the functions receive the messages
   (duplicates) from the queue ?

Thanks -nen

Answer (score 1):

> what would happen when we scale the function app, say if we have 2
> instances of the function, will both the functions receive the
> messages (duplicates) from the queue ?

No. Each Function instance will get different messages. Essentially the messages are fetched in `GET` mode (i.e. they are dequeued) and if a message is dequeued by one Function instance, it will become invisible to other Function instance for a certain amount of time.